# Python AND operator using more than 2 lists

Tags: python, list

I have a question regarding comparison of multiple lists. I have a "master list" and 5 sublists. Some of the items in the 5 sublists are identical, and not all of them match the ones in the master list. I know which of these are in each, however the master list is large. This might be kind of confusing, but I need to identify the overlaps in these sublists to mark for different colors in networkx.

My code right now: (and it doesn't work)

```
master = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
s1 = [ 1, 2, 3]
s2 = [1, 3, 4]
s3 = [1, 2, 6]
s4 = [2, 3, 4]

colors = []
for m in masterlist:
    if m in s1 and m in s2 and m in s3:
        colors.append('magenta')
    elif m in s1 and m in s3 and m in s4:
        colors.append('blue')
    elif m in s1 and m in s2 and m in s4:
        colors.append('green')
    elif m in s1 and m in s3:
        colors.append('cyan')
    elif m in s2 and m in s4:
        colors.append('tan')
    elif m in s1:
        colors.append('aquamarine')
    elif m in s2:
        colors.append('gold')
    elif m in s3:
        colors.append('yellow')
    elif m in s4:
        colors.append('black')
    else:
        colors.append('gray')

print colors
```

Desired output:

```
['gray', 'magenta', 'blue', 'green', 'tan', 'gray', 'yellow', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray']
```

I noticed that the points where it doesn't work are the lines with two AND statements. Does anyone know how I should change this? Should I use something like 'contains'?

I also need to know where the overlaps occur, by color. So I've been using a count method for the colors list:

```
print "s1-2-3 overlaps:", colors.count('magenta')
print "s1-3-4 overlaps:", colors.count('blue')
print "s1-2-4 overlaps:", colors.count('green')
print "s1 unique:", colors.count('aquamarine')
...
```

The output I need based on the example above is a list with color strings. If a item in the master list is contained in all 5 sublists, I need a color name to be in the same position in the color list as the master list. Then for all remaining items in the sublists, I need a different color appended to the color list for each one, with all other items in the master list not matching any sublists, to be colored the same color. Again, this is for a networkx graph. So the colors will correspond to nodes.

I will be doing this 30+ times making many graphs, so I need the colors for matches within the elif statements to remain the same, so that they are same for each. Sometimes items in sublists will match, sometimes they won't.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what types of values are in your lists? Strings? Integers? Etc?

Comment: Random suggestion: since you keep testing `m in s1` and such over and over, maybe evaluate each of them once, assign them to variables (`m1 = m in s1`), and then just test those booleans. Might not solve the problem but it should speed up your code.

Comment: I would also highly recommend looking into using [``set``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this, specifically the ``intersection`` method. Assuming of course you don't have/care about duplicates.

Comment: they are strings of amino acid sequences.

Comment: doesn't set only use two lists as input? matches = set(a,b)...?

Comment: You can simply chain intersections. I.E. ``a.intersection(b).intersection(c)`` will give you the elements that are in ``a``, ``b``, and ``c``. Or you can pass multiple iterators to ``intersection`` to get the same effect.

Comment: basically, I need to test all combinations of the 5 lists to find all overlaps between those and "master" list. Then append a a different color name for each overlap. So in the end those strings that match lists 1,2 are one color, but those left in 1 are another, and those left in two are different as well. And so on

Comment: @aruisdante: I wasn't aware of that. All examples I came across only used two lists. I'll give it a shot

Comment: @aruidante: getting an error trying "if master.intersection(s1).intersection(s2).intersection(s3):" "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'intersection'"

Answer (score 2):

Given the information in your comments, I think something like this is what you are after:

```
master = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}
s1 = {'A', 'B', 'E'}
s2 = {'B', 'D', 'E'}
s3 = {'E', 'A', 'C'}
>>> master.intersection(s1, s2, s3)
{'E'}

>>> master.intersection(s1)
{'A', 'B', 'E'}

>>> master.intersection(s1, s2)
{'B', 'E'}
```

And so on. You should be able to derive how to append the intersections from this pretty easily.

Unless you're looking for **specific** overlaps, I.E. sublists. In which case @stark's answer is probably more useful, however you may be able to accomplish this using set's `subset` or `superset` functionality as well.

**UPDATE 1**

Example of using supersets (obviously not the extensive set, but should get you going in the right direction):

```
masters = [{'A', 'B', 'C'},{'A', 'C'}, {'B', 'C'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'E'}]
s1 = {'A', 'E'}
s2 = {'B', 'C'}
s3 = {'A', 'C', 'E'}
colors = []
for mlist in masters:
    if mlist.issuperset(s1) and mlist.issuperset(s2) and mlist.issuperset(s3):
        colors.append('magenta')
    elif mlist.issuperset(s1) and mlist.issuperset(s3):
        colors.append('blue')
    elif mlist.issuperset(s2) and mlist.issuperset(s3):
        colors.append('green')
    elif mlist.issuperset(s1):
        colors.append('green')
    elif mlist.issuperset(s2):
        colors.append('gold')
    elif mlist.issuperset(s3):
        colors.append('yellow')
    else:
        colors.append('grey')

>>>  colors
['gold', 'grey', 'gold', 'magenta']
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on your further explanation, I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
master = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
s1 = { 1, 2, 3}
s2 = {1, 3, 4}
s3 = {1, 2, 6}
s4 = {2, 3, 4}    

# A color key is (in_s1, in_s2, in_s3, in_s4)
color_map = {(True, True, True, False)  :'magenta',
             (True, False, True, True)  :'blue',
             (True, True, False, True)  :'green',
             (True, False, True, False) :'cyan',
             (False, True, False, True) :'tan',
             (True, False, False, False):'aquamarine',
             (False, True, False, False):'gold',
             (False, False, True, False):'yellow',
             (False, False, False, True):'black',
             (False, False, False, False):'grey'}

def color_key(element):
    return element in s1, element in s2, element in s3, element in s4

def color_list(in_list):
    return [color_map[color_key(element)] for element in in_list]

>>> color_list(master)
['grey', 'magenta', 'blue', 'green', 'tan', 'grey', 'yellow', 'grey', 'grey', 'grey', 'grey']
```

You can further enumerate the permutations (there are `2^num_s` of them) for more colors if you would like. Note that the `sN`'s are `sets` for speed, but could be `lists` if you need duplicate values (though since you're only searching single values, I don't know why you would). This is basically the [bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) or [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) method, though expanded to be a little more explicit as to what it is doing.

Comment: You can also use the `>` operator instead of the `issuperset` method: `if mlist > s1 and mlist > s2 and mlist > s3`.

Comment: Ok, I think your code will work. Thank you. Why do you use {} though? Are they not reserved for dictionaries?

Comment: @user3358205 ``{value}`` can be used to initialize ``set`` literals as well, although not an empty ``set`` (``{}`` is always an empty ``dict``).

Comment: I get an error saying: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'issuperset'" Does it matter if the 'master' is in list format ( surrounded by [] ), and the 's' lists are as well? I don't have it broken up like your answer does.

Comment: @user3358205 yes, it does. The ``issuperset`` method is a member of ``set``, not ``list``. You'll have to cast them to ``set`` as you check. But note that ``sets`` are *unordered*, and obviously don'y allow duplicates. If order matters, or you have duplicates that matter, then ``set`` is not the tool for you.

Comment: @user3358205 it may be helpful to post a simple expected input/output to help guide answers more clearly.

Comment: @aruisdante: I've updated my question to try and reflect better what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, "iterable" means that it supports the machinery used by, among other things, for and while loops:

```
for x in foo:  # foo is an iterable
  ...
```

You can make your own objects iterable if you wish; this allows you to use them in for or while loops, as arguments to methods like map() or in many other places. More info https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a lookup table instead

```
colorlist = ('gray', 'aquamarine', 'gold', 'gold', black' ...etc.
bitmap = 0
if m in s1: 
    bitmap += 1
if m in s2:
    bitmap += 2
if m in s3:
    bitmap += 4
colors.append(colorlist[bitmap])
count[bitmap]++
```

Fill in the lookup table with all 32 colors for 5 variables.
count will have the number of values for each combination.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more please, stark? The colors need to be strings to pass to networkx. Would I just replace the int values in colors to color names? I also need to know the original lists that they came from. See edits to original question

Comment: Updated with answers.